# FancyBox Loading a HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fancybox

I'm trying to load up a page containing a monetary conversion tool within fancy box
check out the link of the not working page

[The link at the bottom of the page should load the fancy box or the Button "Convertir" on the right floating div](http://www.pourvoirieinukshuk.com/forfaitschevreuil.html)

I would like to achieve this. but it doesnt work even tough i tried the same code. Currently theres another code...running on the page, the one below.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VWsRP/303/)

This is my htlm page calling the fancybox

```
        <!DOCTYPE  html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Pourvoirie, Inukshuk, chasse, bécasse,raid, gélinotte, perdrix, chevreuil, ours, ours 
    noir, cerf de virginie, lièvre, bernache, canard, Baskatong, Canada, Québec, Laurentides, 
    Outaouais, motoneige, hiver, pêche, dorée, truite, brochet, ouananiche, esturgeon, achigan, 
    moucheté, hors-piste, poudreuse, tout inclus, chalet, vacances, photo, video, raquette, ski de 
    fond, pêche blanche, chien de traineau,raid</title>
            <meta name="keywords" content="Pourvoirie, Inukshuk, chasse, bécasse,raid, gélinotte, perdrix, 
    chevreuil, ours, ours noir, cerf de virginie, lièvre, bernache, canard, Baskatong, Canada, 
    Québec, Laurentides, Outaouais, motoneige, hiver, pêche, dorée, truite, brochet, ouananiche, 
    esturgeon, achigan, moucheté, hors-piste, poudreuse, tout inclus, chalet, vacances, raquette, 
    ski de fond, pêche blanche, chien de traineau,raid">
            <meta name="description" content="Pourvoirie Inukshuk, organisation de forfaits personnalisés de 
    chasse à la bécasse, cerf de virginie, ours noir. Circuits de motoneige guidés en pistes 
    balisées et hors-piste,raid">
            <!-- CSS -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/social-icons.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
            <!--[if IE 8]>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ie8-hacks.css" />
            <![endif]-->
            <!-- ENDS CSS -->   

            <!-- GOOGLE FONTS 
            <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>-->
            <!-- Converter -->  
            <link href="http://www.pourvoirieinukshuk.com/css/13_black_green/css/www_rate_calc_frame.css" rel="stylesheet" title="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
            <!-- JS -->
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/easing.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>

                <!-- Add jQuery library -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="fancyBox/lib/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="fancyBox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

        <!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="fancyBox/source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancyBox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />

        <!-- Add Button helper (this is optional) -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancyBox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="fancyBox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>

        <!-- Add Thumbnail helper (this is optional) -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancyBox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="fancyBox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>

        <!-- Add Media helper (this is optional) -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="fancyBox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>




            <!-- Nivo slider -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nivo-slider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
            <script src="js/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <!-- ENDS Nivo slider -->

            <!-- tabs -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tabs.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tabs.js"></script>
            <!-- ENDS tabs -->


            <!-- superfish -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/superfish.css" /> 
            <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/superfish-left.css" /> 
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/superfish-1.4.8/js/hoverIntent.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/superfish-1.4.8/js/superfish.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/superfish-1.4.8/js/supersubs.js"></script>
            <!-- ENDS superfish -->

            <!-- poshytip -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/poshytip-1.0/src/tip-twitter/tip-twitter.css" type="text/css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/poshytip-1.0/src/tip-yellowsimple/tip-yellowsimple.css" type=
    "text/css" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/poshytip-1.0/src/jquery.poshytip.min.js"></script>
            <!-- ENDS poshytip -->

            <!-- Tweet -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.tweet.css" media="all"  type="text/css"/> 
            <script src="js/tweet/jquery.tweet.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
            <!-- ENDS Tweet -->



        <script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-45999659-1', 'pourvoirieinukshuk.com');
      ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                /*
                 *  Simple image gallery. Uses default settings
                 */

                $('.fancybox').fancybox();

                /*
                 *  Different effects
                 */

                // Change title type, overlay closing speed
                $(".fancybox-effects-a").fancybox({
                    helpers: {
                        title : {
                            type : 'outside'
                        },
                        overlay : {
                            speedOut : 0
                        }
                    }
                });

                // Disable opening and closing animations, change title type
                $(".fancybox-effects-b").fancybox({
                    openEffect  : 'none',
                    closeEffect : 'none',

                    helpers : {
                        title : {
                            type : 'over'
                        }
                    }
                });

                // Set custom style, close if clicked, change title type and overlay color
                $(".fancybox-effects-c").fancybox({
                    wrapCSS    : 'fancybox-custom',
                    closeClick : true,

                    openEffect : 'none',

                    helpers : {
                        title : {
                            type : 'inside'
                        },
                        overlay : {
                            css : {
                                'background' : 'rgba(238,238,238,0.85)'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                // Remove padding, set opening and closing animations, close if clicked and disable overlay
                $(".fancybox-effects-d").fancybox({
                    padding: 0,

                    openEffect : 'elastic',
                    openSpeed  : 150,

                    closeEffect : 'elastic',
                    closeSpeed  : 150,

                    closeClick : true,

                    helpers : {
                        overlay : null
                    }
                });

                /*
                 *  Button helper. Disable animations, hide close button, change title type and content
                 */

                $('.fancybox-buttons').fancybox({
                    openEffect  : 'none',
                    closeEffect : 'none',

                    prevEffect : 'none',
                    nextEffect : 'none',

                    closeBtn  : false,

                    helpers : {
                        title : {
                            type : 'inside'
                        },
                        buttons : {}
                    },

                    afterLoad : function() {
                        this.title = 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
                    }
                });


                /*
                 *  Thumbnail helper. Disable animations, hide close button, arrows and slide to next gallery item if clicked
                 */

                $('.fancybox-thumbs').fancybox({
                    prevEffect : 'none',
                    nextEffect : 'none',

                    closeBtn  : false,
                    arrows    : false,
                    nextClick : true,

                    helpers : {
                        thumbs : {
                            width  : 50,
                            height : 50
                        }
                    }
                });

                /*
                 *  Media helper. Group items, disable animations, hide arrows, enable media and button helpers.
                */
                $('.fancybox-media')
                    .attr('rel', 'media-gallery')
                    .fancybox({
                        openEffect : 'none',
                        closeEffect : 'none',
                        prevEffect : 'none',
                        nextEffect : 'none',

                        arrows : false,
                        helpers : {
                            media : {},
                            buttons : {}
                        }
                    });

                /*
                 *  Open manually
                 */

                $("#fancybox-manual-a").click(function() {
                    $.fancybox.open('1_b.jpg');
                });

                $("#fancybox-manual-b").click(function() {
                    $.fancybox.open({
                        href : 'iframe.html',
                        type : 'iframe',
                        padding : 5
                    });
                });

                $("#fancybox-manual-c").click(function() {
                    $.fancybox.open([
                        {
                            href : '1_b.jpg',
                            title : 'My title'
                        }, {
                            href : '2_b.jpg',
                            title : '2nd title'
                        }, {
                            href : '3_b.jpg'
                        }
                    ], {
                        helpers : {
                            thumbs : {
                                width: 75,
                                height: 50
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });


            });
        </script>

    </head>

        <body id="body_chevreuil">

                <!-- HEADER -->
                <div id="header">

                    <!-- wrapper-header -->
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <a href="index.html"><img id="logo" src="images/moy/pourvoirieinukshukchasse.png" alt
    ="Meilleure pourvoirie en Amérique du nord" /></a>

                        <!-- search -->
                        <div class="top-search">
                                    <iframe marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" name="wxButtonFrame" id=
    "wxButtonFrame" height="110" src="
    http://btn.meteomedia.ca/weatherbuttons/template5.php?placeCode=CAQC0354&c
    ategory0=Cities&placeCode1=CAQC0185&category1=Cities&containerWidth=150&bt
    nNo=&backgroundColor=blue&multipleCity=1&citySearch=0&celsiusF=C" align=
    "top" frameborder="0" width="150" scrolling="no" allowTransparency="true"
    ></iframe>
                        </div>
                        <!-- ENDS search -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- ENDS wrapper-header -->                    
                </div>
                <!-- ENDS HEADER -->

                <!-- Menu -->
                <div id="menu">



                    <!-- ENDS menu-holder -->
                    <div id="menu-holder">
                        <!-- wrapper-menu -->
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <!-- Navigation -->
                            <ul id="nav" class="sf-menu">
                                <li><a href="index.html">Accueil<span class="subheader">Bienvenue
    </span></a></li>
                                <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="features.html">Forfaits<span class=
    "subheader">Mémorables</span></a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="forfaitsmotoneige.html"><span>Forfaits Motoneige
    </span></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="chasses.html"><span>Forfaits Chasse</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="peche.html"><span>Forfaits Pêche</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="forfaitsactivites.html"><span>Forfaits Aviation et Quad
    </span></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="hebergement.html"><span>Forfaits Hébergement
    </span></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>

                                <li><a href="gallerie.html">Galerie<span class="subheader">Images & Vidéos
    </span></a></li>
                                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact<span class="subheader">Contactez nous
    </span></a></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li style="padding-top:20px; 
    color:#DBDBDB;"><h1>819-430-2831</h1></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li><a 
    href="http://www.pourvoirieinukshuk.com/en/index.html">English <span class=
    "subheader">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<img src="img/social-icons/english.png" width
    ="24" height="18"/></a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- Navigation -->

                        </div>
                        <!-- wrapper-menu -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- ENDS menu-holder -->
                </div>
                <!-- ENDS Menu -->




                <!-- MAIN -->
                <div id="main">



                        <!-- content -->
                        <div id="content">


                                <!-- the tabs -->
                                <ul class="tabs">
                                    <li><a href="#"><span>Nos Chasses au chevreuil</span></a></li>

                                </ul>
                                        <br>            

                                <table class="prices">
                                <tr width="966">

                                            <td id="noBorder"><center>
                                            <div id="pricing-table" >
                                                    <div class="plan" id="most-popular">
                                                        <h3>Plan Américain<span>$2500</span></h3><li><b>
    Toutes taxes comprises</b></li>

                                                        <a class="signup" href="forfaitchevreuilus.html">Voir
    </a>         
                                                        <ul>
                                                            <li><b>7 Nuits</b> Hébergement</li>
                                                            <li><b>6 Jours</b> Chasse</li>
                                                            <li><b>Inclus</b> 3 repas/jour</li>
                                                            <li><b>Inclus</b> Transport Aéroport</li>

                                                        </ul> 
                                                    </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    </td>

                                                  <td id="noBorder"><center>
                                            <div id="pricing-table" >
                                                  <div class="plan">
                                                        <h3>Location territoire<br>Carabine<span>$2000
    </span></h3><li><b>Toutes taxes comprises</b></li>

                                                        <a class="signup" href=
    "forfaitchevreuillocationcarabine.html">Voir</a>

                                                        <ul>
                                                            <li><b>Période de chasse à la Carabine</b></li>
                                                            <li><b>313 acres privés</b></li>
                                                            <li><b>Possibilité d'installer votre roulotte
    </b></li>
                                                            <li><b>Rivière-Rouge, Qc.</b></li>

                                                        </ul> 
                                                    </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                    </td>

    <td id="noBorder"><center>
                                            <div id="pricing-table" >

                                              <div class="plan">
                                                        <h3>Location territoire<br>Arc<span>$1500
    </span></h3><li><b>Toutes taxes comprises</b></li>

                                                        <a class="signup" href=
    "forfaitchevreuillocationarc.html">Voir</a>

                                                        <ul>
                                                            <li><b>Période de chasse à la Carabine</b></li>
                                                            <li><b>313 acres privés</b></li>
                                                            <li><b>Possibilité d'installer votre roulotte
    </b></li>
                                                            <li><b>Rivière-Rouge, Qc.</b></li>

                                                        </ul> 
                                                    </div>


                                                </div>

                                    </td>



                                </tr>
                                </table>    

                                <!-- ENDS FORFAITS -->              

                        </div>
                        <!-- ENDS content -->


                </div>
                <!-- ENDS MAIN -->

                <!-- Twitter -->
                <div id="twitter">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <a href="#" id="prev-tweet"></a>
                        <a href="#" id="next-tweet"></a>
                        <img id="bird" src="img/bird.png" alt="Tweets" />
                        <div id="tweets">
                            <ul class="tweet_list">


                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- ENDS Twitter -->


                <!-- FOOTER -->
                <div id="footer">
                    <!-- wrapper-footer -->
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <!-- footer-cols -->
                        <ul id="footer-cols">
                            <li class="col" align="justify">
                                <h6>Pages</h6>
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="page_item"><a href="index.html">Accueil</a></li>
                                    <li class="page_item"><a href="features.html">Forfaits</a></li>
                                    <li class="page_item"><a href="gallerie.html">Galerie</a></li>
                                    <li class="page_item"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                            <li class="col" align="justify">
                                <h6>Categories</h6>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="forfaitsmotoneige.html">Motoneige</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="chasses.html">Chasse</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="peche.html">Pêche</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="forfaitsactivites.html">Aviation et Quad</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="hebergement.html">Hébergement</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="col" align ="justify">
                                <h6>À Propos de nous</h6>
                                Fort de nos nombreuses années d’expérience dans le tourisme de chasse, de 
    pêche et de motoneige, l’équipe de la Pourvoirie Inukshuk s’engage à vous 
    apporter satisfaction! Tous nos forfaits sont adaptables à vos besoins et il 
    nous fera plaisir d’organiser votre séjour selon vos standards et d’ajuster 
    le tarif en conséquence des services que vous désirez. Par exemple, vous 
    aurez le loisir de louer votre propre véhicule pour assurer vos déplacements 
    ou de préparer vos propres repas dans vos chalets. Vous serez reçus dans un 
    contexte convivial et très agréable, voilà notre garantie!
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                        <!-- ENDS footer-cols -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- ENDS wrapper-footer -->
                </div>
                <!-- ENDS FOOTER -->


                <!-- Bottom -->
                <div id="bottom">
                    <!-- wrapper-bottom -->
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <div id="bottom-text">Pourvoirie Inukshuk&copy tous droits réservés. </a>Tous nos 
    tarifs inclus les taxes!  </div>
                        <!-- Social -->
                        <ul class="social "><li><a href=
    "http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=295703849&trk=nav_responsive_tab_profile/" 
    class="poshytip  linkedin" title="LinkedIn"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/1428569784023359/" class="poshytip  
    facebook" title="Devenez un fan"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com" class="poshytip twitter" title="Suivez nos 
    tweet"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCyuVjE4R4lDJKNGiQTWgPxg" class=
    "poshytip youtube" title="Suivez nos vidéos sur YouTube"></a></li><li><a href=
    "http://www.pourvoiries.com/" class="poshytip fpq" title="Membre de la 
    Fédération des Pourvoirie du Québec"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- ENDS Social -->
                        <div id="to-top" class="poshytip" title="Vers le haut"></div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- ENDS wrapper-bottom -->
                </div>
                <!-- ENDS Bottom -->

             <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <!-- javascript at the bottom for fast page loading -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing-sooper.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.sooperfish.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.kwicks-1.5.1.js"></script>
        <div id="rp_list" class="rp_list">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <div>
                            <img src="images/icons/currency.png" alt=""/>
                            <span class="rp_title">
                        Convertisseur de devises

                            </span>
                            <span class="rp_links">
                                <a class="fancybox" href="#inline1" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet">Convertir</a>

                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div>
            <br><br>
                <a class="fancybox" href="#inline1" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet">Inline</a>

    <div id="inline1" style="width:400px;display: none;">
            <h3>Etiam quis mi eu elit</h3>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam quis mi eu elit tempor facilisis id et neque. Nulla sit amet sem sapien. Vestibulum imperdiet porta ante ac ornare. Nulla et lorem eu nibh adipiscing ultricies nec at lacus. Cras laoreet ultricies sem, at blandit mi eleifend aliquam. Nunc enim ipsum, vehicula non pretium varius, cursus ac tortor. Vivamus fringilla congue laoreet. Quisque ultrices sodales orci, quis rhoncus justo auctor in. Phasellus dui eros, bibendum eu feugiat ornare, faucibus eu mi. Nunc aliquet tempus sem, id aliquam diam varius ac. Maecenas nisl nunc, molestie vitae eleifend vel, iaculis sed magna. Aenean tempus lacus vitae orci posuere porttitor eget non felis. Donec lectus elit, aliquam nec eleifend sit amet, vestibulum sed nunc.
            </p>
        </div>
            <script>
                $(function() {
                    /**
                    * the list of posts
                    */
                    var $list       = $('#rp_list ul');
                    /**
                    * number of related posts
                    */
                    var elems_cnt       = $list.children().length;

                    /**
                    * show the first set of posts.
                    * 200 is the initial left margin for the list elements
                    */
                    load(200);

                    function load(initial){
                        $list.find('li').hide().andSelf().find('div').css('margin-left',-initial+'px');
                        var loaded  = 0;
                        //show 5 random posts from all the ones in the list. 
                        //Make sure not to repeat
                        while(loaded < 1){
                            var r       = Math.floor(Math.random()*elems_cnt);
                            var $elem   = $list.find('li:nth-child('+ (r+1) +')');
                            if($elem.is(':visible'))
                                continue;
                            else
                                $elem.show();
                            ++loaded;
                        }
                        //animate them
                        var d = 200;
                        $list.find('li:visible div').each(function(){
                            $(this).stop().animate({
                                'marginLeft':'-50px'
                            },d += 100);
                        });
                    }

                    /**
                    * hovering over the list elements makes them slide out
                    */  
                    $list.find('li:visible').live('mouseenter',function () {
                        $(this).find('div').stop().animate({
                            'marginLeft':'-220px'
                        },200);
                    }).live('mouseleave',function () {
                        $(this).find('div').stop().animate({
                            'marginLeft':'-50px'
                        },200);
                    });

                    /**
                    * when clicking the shuffle button,
                    * show 5 random posts
                    */
                    $('#rp_shuffle').unbind('click')
                                    .bind('click',shuffle)
                                    .stop()
                                    .animate({'margin-left':'-18px'},700);

                    function shuffle(){
                        $list.find('li:visible div').stop().animate({
                            'marginLeft':'60px'
                        },200,function(){
                            load(-60);
                        });
                    }
                });
            </script>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're loading two different jQuery libraries on line 31 and 39:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="fancyBox/lib/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

Gonna need to lose one of those (I suggest losing the 1.5 since its older!). If you remove the first library (older 1.5) be sure to also move that second library include (1.10) up to where the first library was, so it is included before the other jquery related frameworks.

You've also got what looks like yet another jQuery library called at the end of your page on line 547:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

If that IS a jQuery library, remove it as well (not clear based on that file name).

Comment: Hi I have tried all your fixes, still no luck, this is the link towards the live website and webpage...[link](http://www.pourvoirieinukshuk.com/forfaitschevreuil.html)[/link]

also the script on line 547 is used to have the floating menu on the right....wich is supposed to pop the div id #inline1 within a fancybox.. :)

Comment: I took a look, that last call to "js/jquery.js" is indeed a jQuery library for 1.4. Your fancybox plugin requires 1.6. Remove this call.

Comment: If I remove that lib, my floating tile are not there anymore.. and the link at the bottom of the page to test still doesnt load within a fancybox..I'm starting to loose hair here

Comment: Simply removing a duplicate jQuery library shouldn't effect the "floating tiles", so you've got other issues as well. :) In any case, you can't have two jQuery libraries, so take out 1.4 and work from there.

Comment: I notice you're calling .poshytip() in custom.js, but custom.js is above the poshytip.js library. Move poshytip.js above custom.js.

Comment: Ok you'r a King, I got rid of EVERything, but now that darn line 547, if it aint there the floating menu on the right is not coming out anymore when i hover it, but if i leave the line there then fancybox doesn't work for the reasons you stated before..any ideas..

I even deleted the poshytip because it wasn't needed on this page..